# Delayed shutdown re-executes on restart

Tags: shutdown

I am trying to allow my system (OSMC on RPi3) to run for only 90 minutes in day and then shutdown (to restrict my kids). I used shutdown -P 90 on rc.local. But if system is shutdown before 90 minutes the command is reexecuted on next restart, even if next day. If restarted again second time then it's okay.
Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Regards

Comment: Could you clarify this: `If restarted again second time then it's okay`. What exactly do you do and what happen? Maybe I'm wrong but the behaviour you describe it's the logical one, every time the RPi starts the command `shutdown -P 90` is executed so the RPi will shutdown every 90 minutes after switched on, always.

Comment: Some recommendations for parental control: [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Parental_Control) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68918/how-do-i-restrict-my-kids-computing-time) (the last one is a little bit outdated but can be helpful as start point)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Issue is when pi is shutdown before scheduled time, manually. On next restart it initially shuts down due to previous cmd supposedly left in system. On restart' it starts normally without any issue.